# SimpleInjector named parameter registration

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I have a service constructor with multiple same-type parameters dependencies

```
class Service{
    public void Service (String connectionStringOne, string connectionStringTwo)
    {}
}
```

How can I do this registration in SimpleInjector container.
I assumed I would use RegisterConditional providing the predicate.
e.g.

```
Container.RegisterConditional(typoef(string),"SQLConnectionString",Leftstyle.Singleton, pc => pc.ParameterName == "connectionStringOne")
Container.RegisterConditional(typoef(string),"MDXConnectionStribng",Leftstyle.Singleton, pc => pc.ParameterName == "connectionStringTwo")
```

However the PredicateContext does not provide 'ParameteName'

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Apologies I misspoke. Please see revised question

Comment: The parameter name can be retrieved using `c.Consumer.Target.Name`, although I advice against using RegisterConditional like this. See my answer for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should register your service using a factory delegate:

```
container.Register<IService>(() => new Service("str1", "str2"));
```

Comment: what if instead of hard coded strings I have Session variables that hold the values to be passed or web.config?

Comment: @SimpleFellow those are two very different use cases. Values in the web.config are constant values; they don't change during the application lifetime. You should read them from the config during startup and pass them just like in the given example. Resding a value from the session should be abstracted behind an application-specific abstraction. If you post a new question with more details about your case, I will try to answer it.

Comment: Just consider a case of a class that has a constructor that needs a string. The string that is needed resides in a session variable and for each user it is going to be different. (different sessions/ different string values/ each user has a unique value). What to do in that case?

Comment: @SimpleFellow: Post a new question here on Stackoverflow with a detailed (and realistic) code example of what you're trying to achieve.